# Showering facilities at Kings Cross station - Where are they and what are they like?

Tags: uk, trains, london, hygiene, train-stations

On the [National Rail enquiries page for Kings Cross station](http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/stations_destinations/kgx.aspx), it simply states:

> Showers - Yes

Ideally, I'd like a little bit more information than that! Such as where they are, how much they cost, what's provided, how to pay, what condition they're in, that sort of thing. Anyone know?

Comment: My top 3 questions during travel are: where I am eating next, where I am showering next, where I am sleeping next. I never knew there was a public shower at Kings Cross, or, heck, anywhere in Central London. If I needed this I would've gone the "find a gym" route. This is fantastic information.

Comment: @chx Paddington also offers public paid-for showers, possibly because it too has a fair number of long distance services. St Pancras doesn't seem to, but it's a 2 minute walk to Kings Cross. Euston doesn't have public showers, but does apparently have free ones in the First Class lounge + available for Sleeper customers. Not sure about any others

Comment: @chx I find your three top questions a bit strange, simply because if the answers to the second and third questions are not the same, it's probably someplace I wouldn't want to travel to in the first place. :P

Comment: Showering isn't _always_ a given, every night, while backpacking. Sleeping is, even if its just sitting down and taking a nap. I'll plan to locate showers at least every third or fourth day. If they are available more often, so much the better, and cleaner.

Comment: @MasonWheeler sleeping and showering gets separated when you get on a transatlantic/transpacific flight. You can get a lie flat seat on a lot of planes but getting a shower is a very different matter. So: sleep on a plane, get a shower in transit, get to your hotel/accomodation and sleep (and possibly shower again). I am not doing awfully long train rides but I bet similar concerns arise.

Comment: @chx Admittedly I've never flown across the Atlantic, but I've flown across the Pacific (US <--> Australia) a few times, and between North and South America a few times as well, and in every case I never saw either the need or the opportunity to shower before arriving at my lodging.  (Although I might not have noticed the opportunity because I wasn't looking for it, because I didn't see the need to...)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Because Kings Cross station is one of the handful of big stations both owned and managed by the infrastructure operator Network Rail, the best source of information isn't National Rail Enquires (as normally would be the case), but [Network Rail's own station page for Kings Cross](https://www.networkrail.co.uk/london-kings-cross-station/), and more specifically [the Kings Cross station facilities page](https://www.networkrail.co.uk/london-kings-cross-station/facilities/)

This contains quite a bit more showering details:

> By the entrance to platforms 9-11.
>
> Monday to Sunday 07:00 - 21:00
>
> £5, pay at Excess Baggage, soap included. Towels available - deposit required.

This is almost all correct....

On arrival at Kings Cross, head towards platforms 9-11. Go past platform 9 3/4 (really!), and by the stairs up to the Parcel Yard pub is the Excess Baggage Company office. Go in there, pay them a fiver, and they'll give you a receipt.

Next, follow the corridor by the Excess Baggage Company signposted as Toilets. At that barrier, ring the bell, and show them your receipt. They'll get you a towel (no charge/deposit) and some shower gel, then unlock a hidden door in the appropriate toilet area (male/female). You then go in and lock the door.

The shower, at least on the male side, is in good condition and quite large. The non-shower area in the room is a little small, but does have 3 sturdy coat hooks. One downside - no shower curtain, so you'll need to hang most things up to avoid it getting wet!

Plenty of water pressure (maybe too much given no shower curtain...), nice and warm water, decent shower gel and pretty good towel. For a fiver, and after a long journey, it's not bad.

Comment: I really like it how you can get on this SE site any facility information in increadibly detailed way, on any point on this world. I fear some one could even tell me more about my livingroom, than I can.

Comment: @Zaibis: your curtains are fraying.

Comment: @Zaibis You should really re-upholster that couch. Coffee stains don't go with beige velvet. :)

Comment: @Zaibis Questions about your living room should be asked at the [Home Improvements SE site](http://diy.stackexchange.com/) - they'll be able to tell you useful things you never knew about your living room like, [which of your living room's walls are load bearing](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4/are-there-ways-to-determine-if-a-wall-is-load-bearing), or  [where the electrical wires are inside the walls](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7578/how-do-you-know-when-and-where-it-is-safe-to-drill-into-a-wall)... `:-)`

Comment: So basically, the way to get a shower in King's Cross station is, walk past platform 9 ¾, slip a guy a fiver, then walk through a hidden door.

Comment: (genuine question!) Is it a one-person private shower or a communal area?

Comment: @user568458 In the male area, there's only one shower room, only big enough for one person, and you get exclusive use of it for the duration of your shower. You lock the door when you go in using a toilet-style lock. They clean and lock it (key) afterwards. I assume it's basically the same in the womens

Comment: here http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=shower+dalek&qpvt=shower+dalek&qpvt=shower+dalek&FORM=IGRE you will find many people complaining the sign to tell you where the showers are looks like a dalek

Comment: I'm glad they seem to have moved platform 9 3/4. When I first saw the sign for that, it was on platform 1. (Random fact: J.K. Rowling got confused between Euston and King's Cross.  Euston has a location that could really be platform 9 3/4: platforms 9 and 10 are different sides of the same physical space and platform 10 is longer, so 9 3/4 would be the "back" side of the longer part of platform 10. But it's a good job she said King's Cross, since that looks much nicer in the movies, whereas Euston is underground and hideously, hideously ugly.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The outside shots of King's Cross in the movies are actually of St Pancras, by far the most attractive station in London.

Comment: @RichardGadsden Good point. But the shots on the platform are King's Cross, right?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Give or take anything that was shot on a soundstage, I believe so. King's Cross would be the right station for a train leaving for any part of Scotland north of the Central Belt, of course.